# .gitignore not preventing a directory being pushed to github

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I am building a react native application in which I don't want to push android and ios directories to github. No matter what I am writing in `.gitignore` file, these two directories are always being pushed to the github. Following are the patterns that I have used in `.gitignore`:

```
1. android 
   ios
2. /android/*
   /ios/*
3. android/
   ios/
4. /android
   /ios
```

Please tell me how can I prevent these folders from going to github?

Thanks!!

Guys the numbering and indentation is not real. I have used them just to depict how many ways I have tried.

Comment: You have some formatting issues. You should not use ordered lists in .gitignore. Also, I never tried heading whitespaces in a name, but I suggest caution. That is to say, I don't think you have a folder named "2. /android/" and, even if you have, you'll probably need to escape the whitespace.

Comment: 1) Do you really have number bullets and indents in your `.gitignore`? 2) `.gitignore` is not about _pushing_, it's about _adding to index_ therefore _committing_.

Comment: it is solved by following the given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to add these lines to `.gitignore`

```
android/
ios/
```

Then follow the answer below to untrack committed folders:

[Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)